# JPA - Create Transient primary key

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class mapped to an existing table. This table doesn't have a  primary key. Here is the table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testtable](
[field1] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[field2] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[field3] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[field4] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[field5] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[field6] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
)
```

I can't do any changes to this table and i am trying to find a way to use jpa by setting a primary key only in memory. I know in theory that if i want to have a column only in memory i can use the transient annotation. I would like to set `field1, field2, field3` as a **transient** primary key that will point to the existing database fields. Something like a pointer inorder to be able to get the values of the existing fields. Is this posible??

Here is the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "testtable")
public class TestJPA implements Serializable
{
 @Column(name = "field1")
 private String field1;

@Column(name = "field2")
private String field2;

@Column(name = "field3")
private String field3;

@Column(name = "field4")
private String field4;

@Column(name = "field5")
private String field5;

@Column(name = "field6")
private String field6; 
}
```

Comment: is there any set of fields in the table which uniquely identifies a record?

Comment: your statement that you cant use JPA without PRIMARYKEY is totally made up : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#No_Primary_Key. Please dont state your assumptions like they were fact, thank you very much

Comment: yes. field1 field2 and field3 can identify uniquely a record. or do you mean if there is an id(int) column?

Comment: @specializt wrong expression. edit approved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes. field1 field2 and field3 can identify uniquely a record

In this case consider using [@EmbeddedId](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Embedded_Id) for a composite PK.

**EDIT:** hyperlink updated

As per [Oracle specification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/undejbs003.htm):

> Each JPA entity must have a primary key that uniquely identifies it
>   from other instances. The primary key (or the fields contained within
>   a complex primary key) must be persistent fields.

Comment: thanks a lot.  your answer led me to this example. http://patrickgrimard.com/2011/03/27/using-the-jpa-embeddable-annotation-to-create-your-own-composite-keys/

Comment: didn't know that you can replace `@EmbeddedId` with `@Id`, have to try this out

Comment: btw as soon as your field name matches property name annotation @Column(name=...) could be omitted (Convention over Configuration principle is one of my favorites).

Answer (score 1):

If it is transient than it is not mapped to DB.

The fact that there is no Primary Key defined in DB does not stop you from using one in JPA, DB just does not enforced unique constraints in that case.

What you need it is composite primary key in JPA, which is composed from field1 to field3.

But that will work only if you always want to treat those 3 fields as your 'transient primary key' as you call it.